# How does one implement a local storage array?

Tags: javascript

I tried what made sense:

In the module below `localStorage.foo` works but `localStorage.session_array['privacy']` returns undefined.

This is prototype code for modern broswsers.

```
var ISession = ( function () 
{

    localStorage.session_array = 
    {
        privacy:            0
    };

    localStorage.foo = 1; 

    var SessionI = function ( ) 
    {
    };

    SessionI.prototype.get = function( type ) 
    {
        return localStorage.session_array[ type ];
    };

    SessionI.prototype.set = function( type, value ) 
    {
        localStorage.session_array[ type ] = value;
        alert( '|' + localStorage.foo ); // returns 1
        alert( '|' + localStorage.session_array[ 'privacy' ] ); // returns undefined
    };

    return SessionI;

} ) ();
```

In the mean while I'm just going to implement this using non array properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since localstorage isnt supported by all browsers, you might want to look at [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) instead. It has support for localstorage when available and if not uses some other storage mechanisms (globalStorage and UserData). The best part is you can also store JSON encoded data as well.

```
// Store 'marcus' at 'username'
store.set('username', 'marcus')

// Get 'username'
store.get('username')

// Remove 'username'
store.remove('username')

// Clear all keys
store.clear()

// Store an object literal - store.js uses JSON.stringify under the hood
store.set('user', { name: 'marcus', likes: 'javascript' })

// Get the stored object - store.js uses JSON.parse under the hood
var user = store.get('user')
alert(user.name + ' likes ' + user.likes)

store.set('user', { name: 'marcus', likes: 'javascript' })
alert("Hi my name is " + store.get('user').name + "!")

store.set('tags', ['javascript', 'localStorage', 'store.js'])
alert("We've got " + store.get('tags').length + " tags here")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by global storage and user data...?

Comment: global storage and user data are different types of  local storage mechanisms that are available on different browsers. store.js will use the `localstorage` api if the browser supports it, otherwise on older browsers it will store in globalstorage or userdata (filesystem), however the javascript code to access the data will be the exact same.

Answer (score 3):

localStorage only saves data as strings

Comment: I can't say, but sessionStorage has less persistance. As the name implies the data is only available for the session